# Add foreign key to AspNetUser table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've created an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application with user identities.

The created project includes a migration that adds all the user tables, such as `AspNetUser` and `AspNetRoles`. However, it doesn't create any code models for these tables.

Now I've created my own entity models and I would like some of them to have foreign keys to the `AspNetUser` table.

How can I do this? Does the platform expose these as classes anyplace? Do I need to manually create models and try to get them to exactly match the tables? Or for that matter, how do I access all of a user's details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default identity uses `IdentityUser`, it is not exposed to the project code but you can create a new user model (e.g. `AppUser`) that is derived from `IdentityUser`, then add the foreign keys to the new user model:

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public UserAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class UserAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Then replace IdentityUser in startup with AppUser :

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>();
```

Then create new migrations to create the new user table.

Comment: I did this. But when I ran the program I get an exception: *InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.* Unfortunately, I don't get any line numbers.

Comment: I fix the issue. I had to change the references to `IdentiyUser` to `AppliationUser` in *_LoginPartial.cshtml*.

Answer (score -1):

In case you're still looking for a different solution after 4 years or there are other people looking for this answer, you can add into your model fields of ApplicationUser type

```
public class Messages : BaseEntity
    {
        public string? Message { get; set; }
        public string? UserFromId { get; set; }
        // public string? UserToId { get; set; } 
        public ApplicationUser? UserFrom { get; set; }
        // public ApplicationUser? UserTo { get; set; }
        public string? PostingTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I commented some lines because if you use more then one ApplicationUser it will require additional options to be configured which is not related to question

Just don't forget to add "Id" part to additional field created for ApplicationUser type field, so EFcore understands what field is here to store data of other table

(in my example I'm storing Ids of users into two fields and telling that they both refer ApplicationUser)

Comment: If you want your answer to be deleted you can vote for deletion. If something's wrong with it, please don't "vandalize" the answer, as it's called on Stack Overflow, because the answer isn't yours any more the moment you posted it. You may try to improve the answer.

Comment: sorry @GertArnold I thought simple "delete" button not working was site's bug, and I couldn't do anything about it