# How to implement Entity atribute value model (EAV) using EF Core and ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Let's say I have one entity USER and added some fix properties during the application development. Then after the application deployment if some user wants to add more custom field based on text-field, email, integer, drop-down, multi-line text etc. according to their requirement after the login from the application. How can I make the application such that user can customize the form and add an extra custom field of different data type on the FORM using ASP.NET CORE?

For example, I have added two fields on the **UserProfileForm** during the application development or User has two pre-built custom field for all user.

- FirstName: string
- LastName: string

Then how can I make the application such that other users can customize the **UserProfileForm** such that they can add the custom fields of different data types on that form after the application deployment?

- DateOfBirth: DateTime
- Bio: Text(multiline)
- Profession: DropDown

Comment: See the docs for [customizing identity model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-the-model) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654074/add-foreign-key-to-aspnetuser-table/58654305#58654305) can help you as well

Comment: @LazZiya I want to add an extra custom field from the running application, not during the development phase.

Comment: If you want users to dynamically create properties and assign values for entities, you can check the [entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) models. This architecture allows your application to be customizable at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What is not clear from your question is how you define additional properties. But let's assume you have some admin module, or just simply a form that allows to add random key-value properties. Obviously, if you define a custom field as dropdown, you need to have some admin design that would associate your field with the dropdown values. So, I assume you took care of all this.

The easiest is to have a field in `ApplicationUser` (typical name for the class derived from `IdentityUser`) that has a JSON string with a single object containing all those dynamic values.

```
public  class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string ExtraFields { get; set; }
}
```

That way, the design of `ApplicationUser` model is *fixed*, but you still have the way to store and handle the extra fields dynamically. If you have a class with those dynamic values, you can use `JsonSerializer.Serialize()`, otherwise you probably need to build JSON object "manually"